# Null is not an object (evaluating 'firebase.auth().currentUser.email') : FIREBASE REACT NATIVE (EXPO)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, react-native-firebase

I am using firebase in my react native project in expo CLI. I am trying to get the user information in another file that has been logged in. But for some reason i am facing the error that has been shown in  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRsy5.jpg) screenshot.

[image]

I tried initialising the firebase object in componentWillMount() as well as in the constructor. Yet it is throwing the same error, However if i come back and restart the app. It works just fine.
Dashboard.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View , StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import firebaseConfig from '../config';
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
export class DashBoard extends Component {
    constructor()
    {
        super();  
    }
    render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>Hello {firebase.auth().currentUser.email} </Text>
                </View>
            )
    }
}

export default DashBoard;

const styles= StyleSheet.create({

 container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }

})
```

Answer (score 3):

When the application starts, Firebase may need to communicate with its servers to check if the user authentication is still valid. This happens asynchronously, and while this is going on, `firebase.auth().currentUser` will return `null`. So that's why your `<Text>Hello {firebase.auth().currentUser.email} </Text>` doesn't work: you're calling `.email` on `null`.

The solution is to check if the user is authenticated:

```
<Text>Hello {firebase.auth().currentUser ? firebase.auth().currentUser.email : "unknown user"} </Text>
```

You'll typically want to do this in your regular JavaScript code, instead of in the `render()` method as it makes the code a bit harder to read.

In fact, you'll likely want to push the `user` into the state of your object, and refresh it when the authentication state changes. To do this, you can [attach a so-called auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) and call `setState` from its callback:

```
componentWillMount() {
  firebase.auth().addAuthStateChangedListener((user) => {
    this.setState({ user });
  });
}
```

And then in your render method you'd do:

```
<Text>Hello {user ? user.email : "unknown user"} </Text>
```