# The correct way to delete a user with react-native-firebase from Auth and Firestore at once?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to delete a user from Auth and Firestore on button click in one go using react-native-firebase. My issue at the moment is that it is not deleting the document 'user' from Firestore. BUT, it does look like I am deleting the user from Auth.

Also when I press the button that calls the deleteUserFunc I receive the error:

> "null is not an object (evaluating '(0,
> _auth.default)().currentUser.uid')"

(UID has a valid id on page load)

```
const [_, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;   

const deleteUserFunc = async () => {
        await deleteAccount();
    }

    async function deleteAccount() {
        auth().currentUser.delete().then(() => {
            db.collection('users')
                .doc(user.uid)
                .delete()
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error, "error")
        }).finally(() => setUser((state) => ({ ...state, isLoggedIn: false })))
    }
```

How can I delete from the Firestore for this user, as well as improve the code that I have written.

Any help is appreciated - thank you for your time!

Comment: "I'm having a few issues" Please edit your question to show what issues you are having, including the exact error message and entire stack trace for each.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, fair point! I was tired and frustrated when I wrote this post initially. I have updated this post with a little bit more detail with my issue and the code I have written. Cheers! @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59601773/16531380) that discussed your similar issue/error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you set your `user` variable to point to `auth.currentUser`, which becomes `null` when you delete the current user. So you'll need to either reverse the operations (first delete the document, then the user), or you can capture the UID in a local variable before deleting the user.

The latter would look like:

```
async function deleteAccount() {
    const uid = auth().currentUser.uid; // 
    auth().currentUser.delete().then(() => {
        db.collection('users')
            .doc(uid) // 
            .delete()
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, "error")
    }).finally(() => setUser((state) => ({ ...state, isLoggedIn: false })))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank - that was really helpful. Although, it seems that my Firestore data still exists. I logged it out and got: Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation. Here are how my Firestore rules look... rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
allow read, write: if request.auth != null
 }
  }
}

Comment: That seems like a different problem, but the explanation is the same: if your rules require that the user is signed in in order to be allowed to delete data, you can't delete data anymore after deleting the user. In general, the pattern I follow upon deletion is to reverse the order of when I registered/created the user, so first delete the data, and only then delete the user.